# How do you manage database connections in php?

Tags: php, oop, database-connection, connection-pooling

So recently I've really started to use php actively, and I need some insights on different ways to use database connections.

At first I just used the simple mysql_connect():

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(DB_DB, $connection);
?>
```

After a while I created a database class which I started to include and initialize in every file - something like this:

```
<?php
class MySQL_DB {

var $connection;

function MySQL_DB(){
    $this->connection = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(DB_DB, $this->connection);
}

function query($q){
    $res = mysql_query($q, $this->connection) or die(mysql_error());
    return $res;
}
}

$database = New MySQL_DB;
?>
```

And this is what I'm using at the time - and it's working fine - but there are always ways to improve.

So my question to you is how do you manage your database connections?

- Do you use classes?
- What does your classes contain (just
  the connection or even functions?)
- What practices do you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usage of classes are the way to go to increase customized re-usability.

Bring in all generic implementations into the class. You are on the right track.

<strike>This website has the following clean approach.</strike>
This website link is no longer present. [Archive Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20090831070932/http://osspro.com/5/php-database-connection-class).

```
class connection {
    // Possible Modules are as follows:
    // DBX_MYSQL, DBX_ODBC, DBX_PGSQL, DBX_MSSQL, DBX_FBSQL, DBX_SYBASECT, DBX_OCI8, DBX_SQLITE
    private $module = DBX_MYSQL; 

    private $host = "localhost";
    private $database = "test";
    private $username = "testuser";
    private $password = "testpass";

    private $link;
    private $result;
    public $sql;

    function __construct($database=""){
            if (!empty($database)){ $this->database = $database; }
            $this->link = dbx_connect($this->module,$this->host,$this->database,$this->username,$this->password);
            return $this->link;  // returns false if connection could not be made.
    }

    function query($sql){
            if (!empty($sql)){
                    $this->sql = $sql;
                    $this->result = dbx_query($this->link,$sql,DBX_RESULT_UNBUFFERED);
                    return $this->result;
            }else{
                    return false;
            }
    }

    function fetch($result=""){
            if (empty($result)){ $result = $this->result; }
            return dbx_fetch_row($result);
    }

    function __destruct(){
            dbx_close($this->link);
    }
}
```

Comment: I really liked the fetch function on this one - as well as the saving the results as instance variables. Thanks for this input +1

Comment: -1, for future users, NEVER Store your config information in the same database class. That is in secure and also kills the re usability. Create a config class/page and use constants or something to pass them into the connection class.

Answer (score 9):

I recommend to use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo). Don't reinvent the weel. It's a nice OO-interface to [many database engines](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php).
Additionally I create a small function which just inititializes PDO object. So all connection settings can be changed in one place.

Answer (score 5):

Your current approach is pretty standard, and works well.  I used it for a long time.  It's true that modules like PDO provide base functionality like this now, which is very nice as well and can get you away from problems with home-brew code.

However, I've taken the connection management one step further.  If you get into a complex application, you might get into a situation where you have multiple databases, or heavy database use.  Including a single database connection file and having a global `$database` variable becomes unwieldy for multiple databases, and it's unnecessary for application requests that *might not need* a database connection.  Remember, connecting to the database is expensive.

What I've done is create a singleton DatabaseManager class that handles the database object for me, and makes sure multiple connections to a given DB don't get instantiated.  Instead of initializing a new database object at the top of your app, you simply call on the DatabaseManager every time you need the object.

```
$db = DatabaseManager::getDatabase();
```

Here's an example class that I had whipped up for a CodeIgniter project.  You can see in the `getDatabase()` function it simply loads CodeIgniter's default database object, which you would substitute for your own class (and run the connection routine for it) if you weren't using CI.  This is a pretty simplistic management class, and could be extended to manage multiple connections to different databases fairly easily.

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements the Singleton pattern to prevent multiple instantiations and connections
 * to the application database.
 *
 */
class Database_manager
{
    private static $instance;
    public $db;

    /**
     * Constructor function is declared private to prevent instantiation.
     *
     */
    protected function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Returns an instance of a Database_manager.
     *
     * @return object Database_manager object
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (self::$instance == null) {
            $className = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $className();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function getDatabase()
    {
        $instance = self::getInstance();
        if ($instance->db == null) {
            //utilize CodeIgniter's database loader
            $instance->db = $instance->load->database('',true);
            if (! is_object($instance->db)) throw new Exception("Could not load database.");
        }
        return $instance->db;
    }
}
```

Perhaps the most common advantage I get out of using this style of connection management is when I have to take down an application for database maintenance.  By not instantiating a database connection until I need it, I can easily put up a "maintenance in progress" message on a site (short circuiting normal MVC dispatching), and not worry about requests to the application opening a DB connection while maintenance is in progress.

Answer (score 0):

In your database manager example, you did not define a parent for your class.
Therefore, invoking parent::__constructor() yields an exception,
and also, you cannot use the load property of code ignitor.

Which class did you use as an extension for your DatabaseManager?

Since i do not know where you placed your databasemanager code, nor which class you used  as its parent, i circumvented the exceptions by making the getDatabase() method receive an input parameter which i called $loader.
Normally, this $loader object will be the model class requiring access to a database.

```
public static function getDatabase($loader)   
{  
    $instance = self::getInstance();  
    if ($instance->db == null) {  
            //utilize CodeIgniter's database loader  
            $instance->db = $loader->load->database('default',true);  
            if (! is_object($instance->db)) throw new Exception("Could not load database.");  
    }  
    return $instance->db;  
}
```

Best regards.